# Isn't \usepackage{tikz} removable without changing the result, when there's \documentclass[tikz, border= mm]{standalone}?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found that when I remove `\usepackage{tikz}` when there's `\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}` before, the resulting image is the same even if `\usepackage{tikz}` is removed in that case. So when we don't consider the gray area, `\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalon}` has the same function as `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz}`. But when I search codes, I often see people not removing `\usepackage{tikz}` when there's `\documentclass[tikz, border=... mm]{standalone}`. Isn't `\usepackage{tikz}` removable without changing the result, when there's `\documentclass[tikz, border=... mm]{standalone}`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[axisline/.style={very thick,-stealth}]  

\draw[axisline] (0,0,0)--(1,0,0) node[right]{$x$}; 
\draw[axisline] (0,0,0)--(0,1,0) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[axisline] (0,0,0)--(0,0,1) node[below left]{$z$};

\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can remove `\usepackage{tikz}` if you are giving the option `tikz` to the `standalone` documentclass.

From `standalone.cls`, line 237–242 (for 2015/07/15 v1.2)

```
\sa@clsoption{tikz}[true]{%
    \sa@boolean{tikz}{#1}%
    \ifsa@tikz
        \setkeys{standalone.cls}{multi=tikzpicture,varwidth=false}%
    \fi
}
```

It basically says that if you give `tikz` as a documentclass option, the `sa@tikz` boolean is set to `true`, and the key-value pairs `multi=tikzpicture,varwidth=false` will be given to the documentclass.

From the same file, line 549– 551:

```
\ifsa@tikz
    \RequirePackage{tikz}
\fi
```

Thus, if you give `tikz` as an option to the `standalone` documentclass, it will automatically load the `tikz` package, since `\RequirePackage` is how one loads packages in class files.

---

**Conclusion:** Using

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
```

has the same effect as using

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

for a single `tikzpicture` environment.

*Note:* As @wrtlprnft mentioned in a comment, `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` also sets `multi=tikzpicture` and `varwidth=false`. These extra options make each `tikzpicture` environment have its own page in the resulting output file (see [the `standalone` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) for more details about `varwidth`).

So if you want to make sure the output is the exact same,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
```

is equivalent to

```
\documentclass[multi=tikzpicture,varwidth=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Comment: @Zarko I'm not sure I understand your question completely. Using `\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz}` should not be a problem, as there is no option clash between the two loadings of `tikz`, if that is what you mean?

Comment: Maybe the side effect of `multi=tikzpicture` should also be explained: It causes each `tikzpicture` to be placed on a separate page. This can be quite useful, but it means that sometimes you want to `\usepackage{tikz}` explicitly and don't pass the `tikz` option.

Comment: @wrtlprnft Good point, added :-)